# Disallow PHP page including all URL parameters with robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

How would I disallow all dynamic pages within my `robots.txt`?

E.g.

- `page.php?hello=there`
- `page.php?hello=everyone`
- `page.php?thank=you`

I would like `page.php` AND all possible dynamic versions to be disallowed.

At the moment I have

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /page.php
```

But this still allows e.g. `page.php?hello=there`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've already got should block all access to /page.php for all search engines which respect robots.txt (no matter whether there are any query string parameters provided)

Don't forget robots.txt is only for robots :-) If you're trying to block users from accessing the page you'll need to use .htaccess or similar